# Limitting file upload on a User php

Tags: php

Im new to php please help me, I have a website and people can upload files like pdf, doc,xls and I want to limit the number of file upload. the user after login can see the upload page and upload his files but i want that the user can only upload files 3 times a day if he submitted 3 times in a day then it should not allow the user to upload more files it should give a message that you can not post more that 3 projects per day.

```
My files are: form.php and Uploadfile.php


<?php 
use foundationphp\UploadFile;

session_start();
require_once 'src/foundationphp/UploadFile.php';
if (!isset($_SESSION['maxfiles'])) {
    $_SESSION['maxfiles'] = ini_get('max_file_uploads');
    $_SESSION['postmax'] = UploadFile::convertToBytes(ini_get('post_max_size'));
    $_SESSION['displaymax'] = UploadFile::convertFromBytes($_SESSION['postmax']);
}
$max = 2000000;
$result = array();
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {

    $destination = __DIR__ . '/uploaded/';
    try {
        $upload = new UploadFile($destination);
        $upload->setMaxSize($max);
        // $upload->allowAllTypes();
        $upload->upload();
        $result = $upload->getMessages();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $result[] = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
$error = error_get_last();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>File Uploads</title>
    <link href="styles/form.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Uploading Files</h1>
    <?php if ($result || $error) { ?>
    <ul class="result">
        <?php 
        if ($error) {
            echo "<li>{$error['message']}</li>";
        }
        if ($result) {
           foreach ($result as $message) {
               echo "<li>$message</li>";
           }
       }?>
   </ul>
   <?php } ?>
   <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $max;?>">
        <label for="filename">Select File:</label>
        <input type="file" name="filename[]" id="filename" multiple
        data-maxfiles="<?php echo $_SESSION['maxfiles'];?>"
        data-postmax="<?php echo $_SESSION['postmax'];?>"
        data-displaymax="<?php echo $_SESSION['displaymax'];?>">
    </p>
    <ul>
        <li>Up to <?php echo $_SESSION['maxfiles'];?> files can be uploaded simultaneously.</li>
        <li>Each file should be no more than <?php echo UploadFile::convertFromBytes($max);?>.</li>
        <li>Combined total should not exceed <?php echo $_SESSION ['displaymax'];?>.</li>
    </ul>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload File">
    </p>
</form>
<script src="js/checkmultiple.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


And uploadfile.php

<?php
namespace foundationphp;

class UploadFile
{
    protected $destination;
    protected $messages = array();
    protected $maxSize = 2102400;//51200; //50 KB
    protected $permittedTypes = array(
            'image/jpeg',
            'image/pjpeg',
            'image/gif',
            'image/png',
            'image/webp',
            'application/pdf',
            'application/rar',
            'application/zip',
            'application/x-zip',
            'application/x-zip-compressed',
            'application/vnd.ms-excel',
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
            'application/msword',
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
            'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',
            'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet',
            'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation',
            'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text'   


    );
    protected $newName;
    protected $typeCheckingOn = true;
    protected $notTrusted = array('bin', 'cgi', 'exe', 'dmg', 'js', 'pl', 'php', 'py', 'sh');
    protected $suffix = '.upload';
    protected $renameDuplicates;

    public function __construct($uploadFolder)
    {
        if (!is_dir($uploadFolder) || !is_writable($uploadFolder)) {
            throw new \Exception("$uploadFolder must be a valid, writable folder.");
        }
        if ($uploadFolder[strlen($uploadFolder)-1] != '/') {
            $uploadFolder .= '/';
        }
        $this->destination = $uploadFolder;
    }

    public function setMaxSize($bytes)
    {
        $serverMax = self::convertToBytes(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));
        if ($bytes > $serverMax) {
            throw new \Exception('Maximum size cannot exceed server limit for individual files: ' . self::convertFromBytes($serverMax));
        }
        if (is_numeric($bytes) && $bytes > 0) {
            $this->maxSize = $bytes;
        }
    }

    public static function convertToBytes($val)
    {
        $val = trim($val);
        $last = strtolower($val[strlen($val)-1]);
        if (in_array($last, array('g', 'm', 'k'))){
            switch ($last) {
                case 'g':
                    $val *= 1024;
                case 'm':
                    $val *= 1024;
                case 'k':
                    $val *= 1024;
            }
        }
        return $val;
    }

    public static function convertFromBytes($bytes)
    {
        $bytes /= 1024;
        if ($bytes > 1024) {
            return number_format($bytes/1024, 1) . ' MB';
        } else {
            return number_format($bytes, 1) . ' KB';
        }
    }

    public function allowAllTypes($suffix = null)
    {
        $this->typeCheckingOn = false;
        if (!is_null($suffix)) {
            if (strpos($suffix, '.') === 0 || $suffix == '') {
                $this->suffix = $suffix;
            } else {
                $this->suffix = ".$suffix";
            }
        }
    }

    public function upload($renameDuplicates = true)
    {
        $this->renameDuplicates = $renameDuplicates;
        $uploaded = current($_FILES);
        if (is_array($uploaded['name'])) {
            foreach ($uploaded['name'] as $key => $value) {
                $currentFile['name'] = $uploaded['name'][$key];
                $currentFile['type'] = $uploaded['type'][$key];
                $currentFile['tmp_name'] = $uploaded['tmp_name'][$key];
                $currentFile['error'] = $uploaded['error'][$key];
                $currentFile['size'] = $uploaded['size'][$key];
                if ($this->checkFile($currentFile)) {
                    $this->moveFile($currentFile);
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ($this->checkFile($uploaded)) {
                $this->moveFile($uploaded);
            }
        }
    }

    public function getMessages()
    {
        return $this->messages;
    }

    protected function checkFile($file)
    {
        if ($file['error'] != 0) {
            $this->getErrorMessage($file);
            return false;
        }
        if (!$this->checkSize($file)) {
            return false;
        }
        if ($this->typeCheckingOn) {
            if (!$this->checkType($file)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        $this->checkName($file);
        return true;
    }

    protected function getErrorMessage($file)
    {
        switch($file['error']) {
            case 1:
            case 2:
                $this->messages[] = $file['name'] . ' is too big: (max: ' . 
                self::convertFromBytes($this->maxSize) . ').';
                break;
            case 3:
                $this->messages[] = $file['name'] . ' was only partially uploaded.';
                break;
            case 4:
                $this->messages[] = 'No file submitted.';
                break;
            default:
                $this->messages[] = 'Sorry, there was a problem uploading ' . $file['name'];
                break;
        }
    }

    protected function checkSize($file)
    {
        if ($file['size'] == 0) {
            $this->messages[] = $file['name'] . ' is empty.';
            return false;
        } elseif ($file['size'] > $this->maxSize) {
            $this->messages[] = $file['name'] . ' exceeds the maximum size for a file ('
                    . self::convertFromBytes($this->maxSize) . ').';
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    protected function checkType($file) 
    {
        if (in_array($file['type'], $this->permittedTypes)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            $this->messages[] = $file['name'] . ' is not permitted type of file.';
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected function checkName($file)
    {
        $this->newName = null;
        $nospaces = str_replace(' ', '_', $file['name']);
        if ($nospaces != $file['name']) {
            $this->newName = $nospaces;
        }
        $nameparts = pathinfo($nospaces);
        $extension = isset($nameparts['extension']) ? $nameparts['extension'] : '';
        if (!$this->typeCheckingOn && !empty($this->suffix)) {
            if (in_array($extension, $this->notTrusted) || empty($extension)) {
                $this->newName = $nospaces . $this->suffix;
            }
        }
        if ($this->renameDuplicates) {
            $name = isset($this->newName) ? $this->newName : $file['name'];
            $existing = scandir($this->destination);
            if (in_array($name, $existing)) {
                $i = 1;
                do {
                    $this->newName = $nameparts['filename'] . '_' . $i++;
                    if (!empty($extension)) {
                        $this->newName .= ".$extension";
                    }
                    if (in_array($extension, $this->notTrusted)) {
                        $this->newName .= $this->suffix;
                    }
                } while (in_array($this->newName, $existing));
            }
        }
    }

    protected function moveFile($file)
    {
        $filename = isset($this->newName) ? $this->newName : $file['name'];
        $success = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $this->destination . $filename);
        if ($success) {
            $result = $file['name'] . ' was uploaded successfully';
            if (!is_null($this->newName)) {
                $result .= ', and was renamed ' . $this->newName;
            }
            $result .= '.';
            $this->messages[] = $result;
        } else {
            $this->messages[] = 'Could not upload ' . $file['name'];
        }
    }
}
Thanks/Regards,

Sam
```

Comment: You only want to limit the number of files? Or the size of the files as well?

Comment: I use max_file_uploads 20 and post_max_size 8M which is php default users can upload 20 files and up to 8 MB my concern is that user can only upload 20 files 3 times in one day and 4th time it should give a message that you can not post more that 3 projects in one day. what I want is that I Don't want a user come and uploads and there is not user quota. Thanks...

Comment: I can give you a hint what I want, I received a message while asking a new question in stackoverflow.com : You have reached your question limit
It looks like you might need a break - take a breather and come back soon! 

You've asked 2 questions recently, 

It's been 0 days since you asked your last question. We ask that you wait 7 days before asking again. Use this time to revisit your previous questions, editing to address any issues that folks have pointed out in comments.d

Comment: What I want is that my form.php also say something like this, you have reached posting 3 projects for today.Please come back tomorrow.

Comment: Please, check my edited answer. In short, I think you should go with SQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQL to store the amount of files uploaded by each user. Then you can check in php if a user can upload another file or not with SQL queries.

***EDIT:***

Let's elaborate a little.

There can be 2 ways for achieving this:

**a) server-side.**

As you say, you have a login form. I suppose you have a database with usernames and passwords, right? So, you can add an 'uploads' table in your database with the timestamp of each upload and the username of the uploader.

Then, each time your PHP class is called, you can make a query to your database to see the amount of files the uploader has uploaded within the last 24 hours. If the number is <3 then your PHP class will allow him to upload another one. Else, your PHP class will echo the message you want.

**b) client-side.**

Each time a user uploads a file, the info about his uploads is stored in his localStorage. So, this info will be checked on 'upload' button click event and either he will be allowed to upload or not.

However, as I said, the info is stored in HIS localStorage, so, this method is bypassable by the user. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Thanks treecon, you are right, your a) server-side. option is good can you please let me know how many column should i make in my db?

Answer (score 0):

Improve your upload function and add destination inside UploadFile class for better re-usability and security:

```
class UploadFile
{
    protected $destination = __DIR__ . '/uploaded/';
    protected $messages = array();
    protected $maxSize = 2102400;//51200; //50 KB
    protected $permittedTypes = array(
            'image/jpeg',
            'image/pjpeg',
            'image/gif',
            'image/png',
            'image/webp',
            'application/pdf',
            'application/rar',
            'application/zip',
            'application/x-zip',
            'application/x-zip-compressed',
            'application/vnd.ms-excel',
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
            'application/msword',
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
            'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',
            'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet',
            'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation',
            'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text'   


    );
    protected $newName;
    protected $typeCheckingOn = true;
    protected $notTrusted = array('bin', 'cgi', 'exe', 'dmg', 'js', 'pl', 'php', 'py', 'sh');
    protected $suffix = '.upload';
    protected $renameDuplicates;

    public function __construct($uploadFolder)
    {
        if (!is_dir($uploadFolder) || !is_writable($uploadFolder)) {
            throw new \Exception("$uploadFolder must be a valid, writable folder.");
        }
        if ($uploadFolder[strlen($uploadFolder)-1] != '/') {
            $uploadFolder .= '/';
        }
        $this->destination = $uploadFolder;
    }

    public function setMaxSize($bytes)
    {
        $serverMax = self::convertToBytes(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));
        if ($bytes > $serverMax) {
            throw new \Exception('Maximum size cannot exceed server limit for individual files: ' . self::convertFromBytes($serverMax));
        }
        if (is_numeric($bytes) && $bytes > 0) {
            $this->maxSize = $bytes;
        }
    }

    public static function convertToBytes($val)
    {
        $val = trim($val);
        $last = strtolower($val[strlen($val)-1]);
        if (in_array($last, array('g', 'm', 'k'))){
            switch ($last) {
                case 'g':
                    $val *= 1024;
                case 'm':
                    $val *= 1024;
                case 'k':
                    $val *= 1024;
            }
        }
        return $val;
    }

    public static function convertFromBytes($bytes)
    {
        $bytes /= 1024;
        if ($bytes > 1024) {
            return number_format($bytes/1024, 1) . ' MB';
        } else {
            return number_format($bytes, 1) . ' KB';
        }
    }

    public function allowAllTypes($suffix = null)
    {
        $this->typeCheckingOn = false;
        if (!is_null($suffix)) {
            if (strpos($suffix, '.') === 0 || $suffix == '') {
                $this->suffix = $suffix;
            } else {
                $this->suffix = ".$suffix";
            }
        }
    }

    public function upload($renameDuplicates = true)
    {

$fi = new FilesystemIterator($this->destination, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$totalFiles = iterator_count($fi);
if ($totalFiles <= 3){
        $this->renameDuplicates = $renameDuplicates;
        $uploaded = current($_FILES);
        if (is_array($uploaded['name'])) {
            foreach ($uploaded['name'] as $key => $value) {
                $currentFile['name'] = $uploaded['name'][$key];
                $currentFile['type'] = $uploaded['type'][$key];
                $currentFile['tmp_name'] = $uploaded['tmp_name'][$key];
                $currentFile['error'] = $uploaded['error'][$key];
                $currentFile['size'] = $uploaded['size'][$key];
                if ($this->checkFile($currentFile)) {
                    $this->moveFile($currentFile);
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ($this->checkFile($uploaded)) {
                $this->moveFile($uploaded);
            }
        }
} else {
    die('You can not post more that 3 projects per day!'); //Improve this to a thrown or stuff;
}
    }

    public function getMessages()
    {
        return $this->messages;
    }

    protected function checkFile($file)
    {
        if ($file['error'] != 0) {
            $this->getErrorMessage($file);
            return false;
        }
        if (!$this->checkSize($file)) {
            return false;
        }
        if ($this->typeCheckingOn) {
            if (!$this->checkType($file)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        $this->checkName($file);
        return true;
    }

    protected function getErrorMessage($file)
    {
        switch($file['error']) {
            case 1:
            case 2:
                $this->messages[] = $file['name'] . ' is too big: (max: ' . 
                self::convertFromBytes($this->maxSize) . ').';
                break;
            case 3:
                $this->messages[] = $file['name'] . ' was only partially uploaded.';
                break;
            case 4:
                $this->messages[] = 'No file submitted.';
                break;
            default:
                $this->messages[] = 'Sorry, there was a problem uploading ' . $file['name'];
                break;
        }
    }

    protected function checkSize($file)
    {
        if ($file['size'] == 0) {
            $this->messages[] = $file['name'] . ' is empty.';
            return false;
        } elseif ($file['size'] > $this->maxSize) {
            $this->messages[] = $file['name'] . ' exceeds the maximum size for a file ('
                    . self::convertFromBytes($this->maxSize) . ').';
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    protected function checkType($file) 
    {
        if (in_array($file['type'], $this->permittedTypes)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            $this->messages[] = $file['name'] . ' is not permitted type of file.';
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected function checkName($file)
    {
        $this->newName = null;
        $nospaces = str_replace(' ', '_', $file['name']);
        if ($nospaces != $file['name']) {
            $this->newName = $nospaces;
        }
        $nameparts = pathinfo($nospaces);
        $extension = isset($nameparts['extension']) ? $nameparts['extension'] : '';
        if (!$this->typeCheckingOn && !empty($this->suffix)) {
            if (in_array($extension, $this->notTrusted) || empty($extension)) {
                $this->newName = $nospaces . $this->suffix;
            }
        }
        if ($this->renameDuplicates) {
            $name = isset($this->newName) ? $this->newName : $file['name'];
            $existing = scandir($this->destination);
            if (in_array($name, $existing)) {
                $i = 1;
                do {
                    $this->newName = $nameparts['filename'] . '_' . $i++;
                    if (!empty($extension)) {
                        $this->newName .= ".$extension";
                    }
                    if (in_array($extension, $this->notTrusted)) {
                        $this->newName .= $this->suffix;
                    }
                } while (in_array($this->newName, $existing));
            }
        }
    }

    protected function moveFile($file)
    {
        $filename = isset($this->newName) ? $this->newName : $file['name'];
        $success = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $this->destination . $filename);
        if ($success) {
            $result = $file['name'] . ' was uploaded successfully';
            if (!is_null($this->newName)) {
                $result .= ', and was renamed ' . $this->newName;
            }
            $result .= '.';
            $this->messages[] = $result;
        } else {
            $this->messages[] = 'Could not upload ' . $file['name'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please Elaborate a little bit or give me an example?

Comment: My code didn't work? I used the FilesystemIterator class to count the files of your  directory and only executes the update routine if it's 3 or less.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a user table in you DB. just add a new attribute upload_day_count... 
At every upload you check if the number is at 3 if not then you allow the upload and icrement the attribute value for this user. Day +1 at 00h01min you run a cron Job to reset all values for all users.